# The linux softirq cpu usage looks strange

Tags: c, linux, softirq

I am running a simple program in a client, it continue sending udp packet to a server. The interface of server is a multi-queue netcard, but I set its rx-flow-hash of udp4 to sd. So all packet will be produced in one CPU.

When I receive 40Wpackets/s, the server's that CPU cost 1% in softirq.
When I receive 60Wpackets/s, the server's that CPU cost 8% in softirq.
When I receive 90Wpackets/s, the server's that CPU cosr 100% in softirq.

The received number is get via running `sar -n UDP 1` for a while.
The cpu cost is get via `mpstat -P ALL 1` for a while.

So I am confused about this.

Why it is not linear?

Answer (score 1):

The soft interrupt is executed after a hard interrupt that takes part of the code that does not need to be processed immediately.

So the soft interrupt can be seized by hard interrupt. After a general hard interrupt is executed, a soft interrupt is executed (interrupting the lower half).

But if this time there is a hard interrupt, the soft interrupt will be preempted.

In this way, when the soft interrupt queue after more than 10, will wake up `ksoftirqd` thread to deal with soft interrupt. `Ksoftirqd` thread occupied by the cpu is described in the problem of soft%.

So the package is less time, `ksoftirq` was awakened less, soft% very low. A lot of soft interrupt in the idle process was interrupted by a hard interrupt, cpu consumption is recorded in the idle% inside.

When the load is high, the soft interrupt is interrupted by a hard interrupt, so `ksoftirqd` has been running, so soft% will suddenly increase a lot.